# Pasting from SQL Server Management Studio to Excel concatenates columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation, paste

I'm trying to paste my query results from Mgmt Studio to Excel, but for whatever reason the columns in Mgmt Studio are concatenated into a single column when pasted into Excel.

This doesn't happen to any of my colleagues and we couldn't find any settings for changing this. Any ideas?

Comment: From results to grid or results to text? What exactly have you highlighted, and have you pressed Ctrl + C or right-clicked and used the context menu items there?

Comment: Results to grid and results to text both result in the same behavior. I've tried highlighting several ways (clicking the top left corner to select all, clicking on a cell then typing ctrl-a). I've copied with both ctrl+c and by right clicking and choosing copy. I've pasted with ctrl+v and with right clicking.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, I don't remember ever having this problem. Have you tried to see if this issue also exists in the latest version of Management Studio (SQL Server 2012)? It does not behave that way for me, at least for modern versions of Excel. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Do you mean 2013? I couldn't reproduce the problem copying results from Management Studio 2012 and pasting into Excel 2013.

Comment: Oops. I meant Excel 2010. Strangely, my colleague is now having the same problem. He said this morning he didn't have the problem and now he does. Crazy! Now there are two of us pulling our hair out. :-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is an issue with Excel.

After you paste the results into Excel, go to the "data" option and choose "Text to Columns".  Then click on "delimited" and be sure that "tab" is checked on the next window.

This will convert the data into columns.  And, Excel remembers the settings, so it will paste correctly the next time.

Comment: This makes sense. I restarted Excel and tried again and it worked. My colleague did the same. I guess Excel wasn't interpreting tabs as the delimiter. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had used text to columns the other day for splitting some other data.  I didn't realise that it had "persisted" the setting (I don't generally use that feature much), and I wasn't expecting it to impact pasting into excel without any interaction, but there you go - learn something new every day.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Be aware that if you have an xml column in your query results, this seems to mess this up. Had to remove to get this to work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. Yesterday it worked, but today it just pasted everything into the first column as text. Used to automatically be pasted from the Management Studio columns into Excel columns.

It's Excel. It remembers your text-to-column choices from last time you used the function in Excel and applies them automatically next time you copy-paste.

You can indeed just use the text-to-columns function again with tabs selected as delimiter. Then after that this choice is remembered and stored in Excel. Now if you copy from Management Studio again and paste it will snap into the columns as expected.

Seems it's one of those instances where Excel tries to help you but ends up being a bit annoying :)

Comment: the technical term for trying to help, but mucking it up is 'hepping'. Excel heps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem in my SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS: it has possibility to export grid as native OpenXMLSpreadsheet, which can be easily "understood" by excel. As "bonus" to solution of your problem you will also see that even datatypes are preserved, so no problems anymore with conversion of dates to text or text to numbers... Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this hint, it worked for me. After installing this software , community version(http://www.ssmsboost.com), I was able to correctly export the data to Excel by using the same command that didn't work prior to installation (right click on top left of the result grid and pick options 'copy' or 'copy with headers').

Comment: Do not download ssmsboost. They have stopped updating the product since april 2021 without any communication with us users. Andrei Rantsevich who is the author of ssmsboost, is nowhere to be seen, neither on Stackoverflow, their facebook or their own homepage. (The product was very good though)

Comment: We just released new version version with SSMS 19.x support. I am very sorry for the interrupted release cycle. I am happy we are back online.

Answer (score 0):

I get this too and in the past i would shut down excel.  I realized after a while that every day i do text to columns for a specific spreadsheet and i change the delimiter to other /.  When i change it back to tab, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with that code:

```
SELECT ID,LastSuccessfullyTransferTime   FROM GP_TRANSFER_LOGS
```

I used that code and problem solved:

```
SELECT ID,FORMAT(LastSuccessfullyTransferTime,'dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM') TransferTime FROM GP_TRANSFER_LOGS
```

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue. I was able to get my results to a CSV using the following solution:

1. Execute query
2. Right click in the top left corner of the results grid
3. Select "Save Results as.."
4. Choose csv and viola!